# GDAL201.dll missing from your computer error on Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, gdal

Using Visual studio 2012

I followed steps into building gdal `using` `nmake`

warmerda/bld and all folders and files created.

But when I include folders (include/lib  and gdal_i.ib) on my c++ project and `<gdal_priv.h>` as soon as run the program.

I get an error message:

> the program can't start because gdal201.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

Any ideas? I'm quite stuck here.

Comment: Insall the c++ redistributables.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: Is `gdal201.dll` in one of the paths in PATH environment variable? If not you may want to just copy it to the same location as your application exe. Also make sure the gdal binary you use was compiled with `Visual Studio 11 2012`. Binaries for any other compiler or a different version of Visual Studio will be incompatible.

Comment: Do you any idea what is this messages means?   Information not available, no symbols loaded for gdal201.dll, after declaring OGRSpatialReference oSRS, i am getting that messge.

Comment: It means the pdb file for `gdal201.dll` was not in your path. You can ignore this warning if you don't need to debug inside of that dll. Given your unfamiliarity with how dlls work my advice is to just ignore this warning. It will not cause your program to fail or anything bad..

Comment: Thanks, i thought something was wrong becuase all im getting is 0x0000000 on gdalopen, and i got that message. when i declare the OGRSpatialReference. Sorry GDAL and c++ newbie, still crawling to make this thing work

Answer (score 0):

When I placed the .dll in the folder with an executable, I was prompted for another .dll. 
Instead of coping it as well, I have changed the folder to the one with all .dll files and run ogr2ogr from there.